# Make THREE.TextGeometry viewable from one side only

Tags: math, three.js

I've been having issues making this work. For a normal mesh I would set material property to THREE.FrontSide, that doesn't seem to do the job for text.

What I've done while working on this once earlier was calculating the angle between the normal of the text mesh and vector pointing from camera towards text mesh on each camera update. I can't seem to get that to work right now because I don't know world coordinates of the mesh because it's being added as child later on in the process.

What I'm trying to achieve is preventing text being viewed from the back and having the letters be backwards. The idea was that I have two meshes with one sided materials or flipping the mesh when I detect camera is looking at it from the back.

If the rotation seems to be the right approach (I doubt it is...) I can update the post with the code I've been trying to get to work.

Comment: You are using 3D `TextGeometry`. Would 2D text be acceptable (like a plane)? How about 3D geometry that always faces the camera? Or just use CSS.

Comment: If there's any possibility to get it to work as it is I'd go for that over any of those approaches. I thought about options you listed and for my use case having TextGeometry just makes way more sense.

I'm showing numbers representing dimensions over a line in space. I guess using a kind of billboard (3d geometry that always faces the camera) is my 2nd option... but as I said, getting TextGeometry to work would be way nicer.

Comment: If you want to keep the 3D text, then you can set `mesh.visible = false` or, alternatively change the mesh rotation by 180 degrees, whenever the mesh is facing away from the camera.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, rotating it by 180 degrees when it's facing away. The approach I tried using was calculating the angle between vector pointing from camera to the text mesh and text's normal vector. I can't seem to get it to work and I think the issue is that text mesh is a child of the line it sits on, so the positions I'm using aren't valid. Is there an easier way to do detect this?

Comment: Please modify your post (and post title) and ask your modified question. Please show a simple live example so it is clear exactly what you are trying to calculate and exactly what your question is.

Comment: To tell you the truth, what you say you want to do is tricky. Consider using sprites for your text, instead, which will always face the camera: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Labeled-Geometry.html